# Gram-Schmidt Calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Does someone knows how to calculate to make these 3 vectors below to a Ortonormal basis:

[image]

I know how to use Gram-Schmidt but i lose myself in these calulations?
Because these Calculations contains fractions i get lost?

First i choose this vector below:

[image]

But after i should do this according to the Gram-Schmidt formula:

[image]

I get lost when i should calculate the Projection formula and take it minus the vector 1 it becomes weird should i use the magnitude in the projection formula because i get in the projection formula and here in
the projection formula i get something divided by something it feels weird??

Should i use the magnitude in the projection formula or?

And after that how should make it to an unit vector??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your calculations up to the step you get lost in. It might help a bit to write the first vector as $\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-2,-4,3)$ and similarly for the other two.

Comment: First, given $\vec v_1$, normalize it: $$\vec u_1=\frac{\vec v_1}{\sqrt{\vec v_1\cdot\vec v_1}}$$

Comment: @Andrei Should i Normalize v1 first and then use Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Correct. That's the only way to get the correct projection. Then normalize $\vec u_2$ before you start calculations for the third vector.

Comment: @Andrei In the Projection formula should i use the magnitude and square it?

Comment: If you normalize to $1$, the magnitude is $1^2=1$.

Comment: @Andrei could you write an Answer to this problem what you mean by normalization in the Calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up Gram-Schimdt process, for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), you might notice that one starts from a set of vectors $\vec v_i$, calculates some orthogonal vectors $\vec u_i$, which then are normalized to get $\vec e_i$. The important part is how one calculates $\vec u_i$:
$$\vec u_i=\vec v_i-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\mathrm{proj}_\vec{u_j}(\vec v_i)$$
The projection operation is $$\mathrm{proj}_\vec{u_j}(\vec v_i)=\frac{\vec{u_j}\cdot \vec{v_i}}{\vec{u_j}\cdot\vec{u_j}}\vec{u_j}
$$
This is followed by normalization of the vectors:
$$\vec e_i=\frac{\vec u_i}{\sqrt{\vec u_i\cdot \vec u_i}}$$
Notice that we can write the projection operator in terms of $\vec e_i$, which would reduce the number of calculations:
$$\mathrm{proj}_\vec{u_j}(\vec v_i)=\frac{\vec{u_j}\cdot \vec{v_i}}{\sqrt{\vec{u_j}\cdot\vec{u_j}}}\frac{\vec{u_j}}{\sqrt{\vec{u_j}\cdot\vec{u_j}}}=(\vec e_j\cdot\vec v_i)\vec e_j=\mathrm{proj}_\vec{e_j}(\vec v_i)
$$
So You calculate first $\vec e_1$:
$$\vec e_1=\frac{\vec v_1}{\sqrt{\vec v_1\cdot\vec v_1}}=\frac{(-2,-4,3,0,0)}{\sqrt{29}}$$
Now calculate $\vec e_1\cdot \vec v_2$, and you will get $$\vec u_2=\frac13(1,-7,0,3,0)-\frac{26}{3\cdot 29}(-2,-4,3,0,0)$$
From here is just arithmetic, and repeat a similar procedure for $\vec e_3$.